# Visual C Multithreaded file reading

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-c++, binaryfiles

I am parsing about 8 GB and naturally I want to optimize my memory and processor use as much as possible. I am reading a file into a buffer 1 page at a time (4096 bytes) it reads the whole thing in about 30 min (which is hours faster than python) but I wanted to make it better. I figured that multithreading was the way to make that happen but I don't know how to do it in C. The samples I've seen are impressive but overly complicated. I was hoping someone could boil down what the base components are for using C's multithreading functionality and give me a heads up about any concurrency problems I will be experiencing. Thank you for any help you can provide.

to clarify, what I am looking for is something extremely basic, like create 2 threads which each print hello world 4 times for example.

imagine I have 4 threads searching 81920 bytes (20 pages).

```
thread 1: searches page 1
thread 2: searches page 2
thread 3: searches page 3
thread 4: searches page 4
---assume they finish in order---
thread 1: searches page 5
thread 2: searches page 6
thread 3: searches page 7
thread 4: searches page 8
---assume they finish in order---
thread 1: searches page 9
thread 2: searches page 10
thread 3: searches page 11
thread 4: searches page 12
---assume they finish in order---
thread 1: searches page 13
thread 2: searches page 14
thread 3: searches page 15
thread 4: searches page 16
---assume they finish in order---
thread 1: searches page 17
thread 2: searches page 18
thread 3: searches page 19
thread 4: searches page 20
```

the reason this is so important is because for each byte in that 81920 bytes (in reality we would want to add on about 5 more 0's I am calling [wcscpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscpy/) up to 5x

I think I found what I'm looking for: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/kdzttdcb(VS.80).aspx) the second example is about the level of complexity that I was looking for. I think that does it thanks.

Comment: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/134584-multithreading-file-reading.html  may be this will help you

Comment: C or C++? Because your tags don't make it obvious. Also, can you use C11?

Comment: CoffeeandCode sorry, there was no visual-c tag defined and I am a newbe as far as stack overflow is concerned. I meant C. I uditr043 I was looking for C but thanks for the link, I will have to study that

Comment: Considering that I just read a 13gb file in 119 seconds off of a mechanical disk drive I'd guess the file i/o is not what's making your program slow.  Make sure you're running a release build, and consider testing with different buffer sizes.  I used a 1mb buffer, but a quick test with a 4k buffer didn't make a difference but all my program does is read.  What are you doing with the data after you read it?  Have you profiled to make sure that the file i/o is in fact the slow part?

Comment: I am reading an 8 GB binary file and searching for all occurrences of 5 specific `wchar_t *` substrings. It probably isn't the file io which is slowing it down, but what I want to splinter off into different threads is the processing of each page.

Comment: Since your title specifies file reading it seemed like that was what you were interested in.  Do your strings cross the boundaries of the blocks you are reading?  You might be able to speed up the searching with multiple threads, but you might also be able to speed up the algorithm you're using to search.  Hard to say really without knowing how your code works.  You might consider asking on Code Review if you're willing to post your working code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja my code works there is no way of speeding it up, I have basically no information as to how the data is actually stored, I just need to do a brute force search. I am just looking for a simple bare bones example of a C thread. I just mentioned files in an attempt to add some context. Seems to have backfired on me ;)

Comment: You could consider learning OpenMP, which abstracts the concurrency away into #pragma statements.  You don't really need general purpose threading and synchronization.  What you need is concurrent processing, which is exactly what OpenMP is good at.

Comment: @paddy I am not familiar with OpenMP, but the reason I am using C is to cut off as much overhead as possible, does it have much?

Comment: OpenMP is an extension to your C compiler.  I'm not suggesting another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the file into memory.  See the MSDN example ["Creating a View Within a File"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366548.aspx) for details on how to do this.  Your use case is a bit different, but the principle is the same, and you'll end up using the same Windows functions.  (If you're in a 64-bit process, you can probably map your entire file into memory; otherwise you'll need to map it in chunks and handle the case where matches span multiple chunks.)

You can use [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) to create multiple threads to process the data in chunks.

> I am reading an 8 GB binary file and searching for all occurrences of 5 specific `wchar_t*`

If this is all that you're doing, then this workload will almost certainly be I/O bound, and multiple threads may or may not help you.  A substring search of this sort can be done using a single pass over the data in question, using e.g., [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for a single pattern or [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) for multiple patterns.